# Rails: Joining by one table OR another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, union, rails-activerecord

I'm looking for a more efficient way to write an ActiveRecord query. I want to get all instances of a model that *either* join one table *or* another table. Both is easy, but either is difficult.

Right now, I have the following two queries:

```
across_clues = Clue.joins(:across_cells)
down_clues = Clue.joins(:down_cells)
```

(Followed by the unsatisfactory `clues = (across_clues + down_clues).uniq.sort_by{|clue| clue.id}` )

I'm wondering how to write a **single** query that will give me the union of both of my queries. That way I can let Postgres do the heavy lifting and keep Rails from getting its hands dirty.

I know how to get the *intersection* of the two sets:

```
bad_clues = Clue.joins(:across_cells, :down_cells)
```

but I haven't seen a good way to get their union. Any help would be appreciated and loved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is you need to use `find_by_sql` and `UNION DISTINCT`

I am a MySQL guy so here is how I would do it

```
Clue.find_by_sql("(SELECT clue.* FROM clue
                       INNER JOIN across_cell ON across_cell.clue_id=clue.id) 
                   UNION DISTINCT 
                  (SELECT clue.* FROM clue 
                       INNER JOIN down_cell ON down_cell.clue_id = clue.id)")
```

Comment: Works great -- I just slightly modified it as shown in my answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

(For posterity)

I used UNION DISTINCT according to shiva's answer, but just slightly modified it to be less hard-coded:

```
across_query = Clue.joins(:across_cells).to_sql
down_query = Clue.joins(:down_cells).to_sql
clues = Clue.find_by_sql("(#{across_query}) UNION DISTINCT (#{down_query})")
```

It works!

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
across_clues = Clue.joins(:across_cells)
down_clues = Clue.joins(:down_cells)

Clue.where do 
(id.in across_clues.select{id}) | (id.in down_clues.select{id})
end
```

with Squeel?